# Summation (Sigma) Formatting in Excel

Tags: excel, sum, formatting

I have an equation that I am trying to format in Excel:

Sigma (from 1 to n) where n=10 of (xi-xo)^2

I have 10 values for xi and xo=0.5 for this particular problem. How would I go about summing this?

Comment: your ten values are in ten consecutive cells? and x in another cell?

Answer (score 0):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A10-B1)^2)
```

Where A1:A10 holds the 10 numbers `xi` and B1 holds `xo`